# How Tomcat cookies are formed?

Tags: session, tomcat, servlets, cookies, tomcat7

How exactly and when exactly tomcat session cookies are formed.

I can see `COOKIE_SUPPORT`, `GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID`, `JSESSIONID`, `LOGIN`, I've [downloaded](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/) source code, but nevertheless cannot see full picture (actually, I can find only `JSESSIONID`).

It would be nice if you also provide any worthy link about how exactly tomcat sessions are configured and organized.

Comment: Only `JSESSIONID` is specific to servletcontainers. The remnant are likely specific to the webapplication itself or to some proxy in front of Tomcat, if any.

Comment: @BalsucC, thank you for this tip, but I don't have any hint, what kind of proxy it is ( technically there is no proxy (but I am far away from seasoned tomcat user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `JSESSIONID` is specific to servletcontainers. The remnant are specific to [Liferay](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/CookieKeys.html) portlet framework which your webapplication is apparently using.

Comment: silly me, no it was a pure tomcat instance, but i forgot about domain cookies. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the others, but for JSESSIONID you should read the servlet spec for when sessions are to be created. In these specs are features that must be implemented by compatible servlet containers.

[Servlet 2.4 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=154), SRV.7 Sessions.

[Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315).

[Servlet 3.1 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340).